# IllegalStateException: fact was never inserted, so it cannot update

Tags: timefold

I have separate CH phases for initialization of my two planning entity classes RestBreak and DutyGrain. The class DutyGrain includes a boolean shadow variable resting which is updated whenever the begin time of a RestBreak changes.
In addition I have a hard constraint punishing any assignment to a DutyGrain if its shadow variable resting is set to true. The planning variable in DutyGrain needs to be nullable, so this constraints selects all including null values.
During the first CH phase initializing all rest breaks this hard constraint produces an IllegalStateException saying the fact (DutyGrain) was never inserted, so it cannot update.

Changing the order of the CH phases makes no sense.
Is there are way to make all entities known before starting the first CH phase?
Or is it possible to filter entities that are not yet known in constraint streams?

Comment: All entities are always inserted, CH has no influence over it. Likewise, what you do in constraints (filtering or not filtering) can not produce the exception you're describing. The exception exists to indicate a deeper issue - if I had to guess, one of your variable listeners is doing something it shouldn't. But it could also be a bug in Constraint Streams; from the information I have, it's impossible to say. Run with TRACED_FULL_ASSERT environment mode and report back; if you get a score corruption before it gets to this exception, it is more likely that var listeners are your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! In fact, I got this exception with FULL_ASSERT environment mode. I tried again with TRACKED_FULL_ASSERT, same result. There is the mentioned exception without any prior score corruption. I should add that in fact this variable listener is updating two shadow variables in different entity classes. Next to class DutyGrain it also updates another planning entity class DutyWithQualifications with a PiggybackShadowVariable annotated shadow variable.

Comment: It could be a bug. If you file Timefold Solver issue on Github and provide a way for me to reproduce the problem on my machine, I'll look into it when time permits.